# Undefined reference error in v8.h while compiling the swig wrapped cxx file

Tags: javascript, c++, swig

I'm trying to convert my C++ project to javascript using swig.I am successfully able to generate the wrap_file.cxx but I'm not able to compile it further to generate the JS file.While compiling it gives me the following error

```
date_wrap.cxx: In function 'void SWIGV8_AddStaticVariable(v8::Handle<v8::Object>, const char*, SwigV8AccessorGetterCallback, SwigV8AccessorSetterCallback)':
date_wrap.cxx:1524:87: warning: ignoring return value of 'v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Object::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::AccessorNameGetterCallback, v8::AccessorNameSetterCallback, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute, v8::SideEffectType)', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
 1524 |   obj->SetAccessor(SWIGV8_CURRENT_CONTEXT(), SWIGV8_SYMBOL_NEW(symbol), getter, setter);
      |                                                                                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from date_wrap.cxx:171:
/usr/include/node/v8.h:3454:37: note: declared here
 3454 |   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> SetAccessor(
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.1.0/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvkThrk.o: in function `SWIG_V8_Raise(char const*)':
date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xae6): undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xaee): undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xb07): undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xb0f): undefined reference to `v8::Exception::Error(v8::Local<v8::String>)'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xb1a): undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::ThrowException(v8::Local<v8::Value>)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvkThrk.o: in function `SWIG_V8_ConvertInstancePtr(v8::Local<v8::Object>, void**, swig_type_info*, int)':
date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xb5d): undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xb6f): undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xb7e): undefined reference to `v8::Object::InternalFieldCount()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xce3): undefined reference to `v8::Object::SlowGetAlignedPointerFromInternalField(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xde2): undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xe04): undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvkThrk.o: in function `SWIG_V8_GetInstancePtr(v8::Local<v8::Value>, void**)':
date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xe9d): undefined reference to `v8::Value::IsObject() const'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xeba): undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xec2): undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrentContext()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xecd): undefined reference to `v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xeee): undefined reference to `v8::V8::ToLocalEmpty()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0xf16): undefined reference to `v8::Object::InternalFieldCount()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1078): undefined reference to `v8::Object::SlowGetAlignedPointerFromInternalField(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvkThrk.o: in function `SWIGV8_SetPrivateData(v8::Local<v8::Object>, void*, swig_type_info*, int)':
date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x115b): undefined reference to `v8::Object::SetAlignedPointerInInternalField(int, void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x116b): undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x11bb): undefined reference to `v8::V8::DisposeGlobal(v8::internal::Object**)'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1227): undefined reference to `v8::V8::GlobalizeReference(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object**)'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x12a7): undefined reference to `v8::V8::MakeWeak(v8::internal::Object**, void*, void (*)(v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void> const&), v8::WeakCallbackType)'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x12f6): undefined reference to `v8::V8::MakeWeak(v8::internal::Object**, void*, void (*)(v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void> const&), v8::WeakCallbackType)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvkThrk.o: in function `SWIG_V8_ConvertPtr(v8::Local<v8::Value>, void**, swig_type_info*, int)':
date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x13f8): undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x140a): undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x15a6): undefined reference to `v8::Value::IsObject() const'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x15c3): undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x15cb): undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrentContext()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x15d6): undefined reference to `v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x15f7): undefined reference to `v8::V8::ToLocalEmpty()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x164e): undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
/usr/bin/ld: date_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x1670): undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
```

date_wrap.cxx is the wrapped file.Im using the latest version of node js and I have also failed trying follow the other methods here http://swig.org/Doc3.0/Javascript.html

Comment: SWIG will net you a node.js extension that wraps your C++ library. It looks like you are trying to compile the wrapper code into a C++ binary. What are you actually trying to do? If you want a node.js extension, you will need to follow the steps under "26.3 Integration" in addition to producing the wrapper C++ file.

Comment: If you wanted to actually compile a C++ library to JavaScript, this is the wrong tool. Look into Emscripten (C++ to asm.js/WASM) or Cheerp (C++ to JavaScript)

Comment: It looks like you've accidentally compiled this as an executable instead of as a shared library. (Undefined reference to main being a big hint here). You might also need to link against a v8 library (e.g. `-lv8`), but I'm less sure on that.